# Need help with polymorphic join table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

Hi gys i am trying to link two entities to one entity which is governing body, estate and repo_document, then a governing body can have repo_document that the estate can also have so i decided to create a join table named document_owner.. but i dont know what to write in their models..i have got this code in my document_owner model..

> ```
> belongs_to :repo_document
> belongs_to :estate, :through => :repo_document, :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => "owner_type = 'Estate'"
> belongs_to :governing_body, :through => :repo_document, :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => "owner_type = 'GoverningBody'"
> belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
> ```

and this one in my repo_document

> ```
>  has_and_belongs_to_many :owners, :join_table => :document_owners, :conditions =>     "owner_type = 'Estate' OR owner_type = 'GoverningBody'"
> ```

and this one in my estate

> ```
> has_many :repo_documents, :source => :document_owners, :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => "owner_type = 'Estate' "
> ```

and this one in my governing_body

> ```
> has_many :repo_documents, :source => :document_owners, :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => "owner_type = 'GoverningBody' "
> ```

but when i try to save it does not save anything inside the join table..

can anybody help me please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as advice, I think polymorphic join tables are a really bad idea and should be avoided except when strictly necessary. Not only are they very difficult to index correctly, but they will make every query involving them a few degrees more complicated and that much harder to scale. Ideally any polymorphic associations you have will never be used to join two tables together.

Further, use of has_and_belongs_to_many is deprecated, were the use of has_many :through is a much better solution in most situations.

One way to simplify this is to combine your Estate and GoverningBody models into a single table, perhaps using STI to distinguish between the two. That way the relationship between documents and this particular entity is much more obvious.

If that's not practical, then you may be better off having two straightforward join tables rather than a polymorphic one.

Polymorphic associations are best for somewhat casual relationships that are one to many. For example:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  # This model has notes
  has_many :notes, :as => :record
end

class Note
  # Can be attached to any kind of record
  belongs_to :record, :polymorphic => true
end
```

In this case, a Note is something that can be attached to any kind of record. Importantly, it is not used in the middle of a relationship, it is an end-point.

Comment: What do you recommend for something like images, which may be attached to multiple objects such as "Event" and "User?"

Comment: If these are peripheral leaf-type entities then it's probably okay to use a compound key and a polymorphic association much like the Note in the example here. When these relationships are used in a `JOIN`, though, it's best to have special purpose tables like `user_images` or `event_images` because the indexes are much less expensive to navigate and update. These concerns are really only relevant at scale, like more than 10^6 records.